# Testing spring controllers and setting up Junit test

Tags: spring-test

Okay, this is probably an ID10T error somewhere, but I just am not seeing it.  I have just a shell of the test but I am seeing the methods get, status and content saying unresolved.  I don't know what I am missing either in the pom or for an import.  I am missing something somewhere, just not seeing it.

Here is the unit test shell.

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

import com.dstbs.prime.service.interfaces.AccountServiceI;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:src/test/test-context.xml"})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class AccountControllerTest
{   
    @Mock
    private AccountServiceI acctSrvc;     

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() { 
        // Process mock annotations
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        // Setup Spring test in standalone mode
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new AccountController()).build();        
    }

//BELOW SAYS THAT get(), status() and content() are unresolved.
    @Test
    public void testGetAccount() throws Exception {
mockMvc.perform(get("/account").accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json")))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"));
    }
}
```

Here are the spring and mockito pom entries I have

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the necessary static imports.

See the [Static Imports](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-server-static-imports) section of the Spring Reference Manual for details.